# User-defined function not returning correct results in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: user-defined-functions, azure-cosmosdb

We are trying to use a simple user-defined function (UDF) in the *where* clause of a query in Azure Cosmos DB, but it's not working correctly. The end goal is to query all results where the timestamp `_ts` is greater than or equal to yesterday, but our first step is to get a UDF working.

The abbreviated data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_ts": 1500000007
    }
    {
        "_ts": 1500000005
    }
]
```

Using the Azure Portal's Cosmos DB *Data Explorer*, a simple query like the following will **correctly** return **one** result:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >= 1500000006
```

A simple query using our UDF **incorrectly** returns **zero** results. This query is below:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >= udf.getHardcodedTime()
```

The definition of the function is below:

```
function getHardcodedTime(){
    return 1500000006;
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the UDF for verification:

[image: Screenshot of UDF in Azure Portal]

As you can see, the only difference between the two queries is that one query uses a hard-coded value while the other query uses a UDF to get a hard-coded value. The problem is that the query using the UDF returns **zero** results instead of returning **one** result.

Are we using the UDF correctly?

**Update 1**
When the UDF is updated to return the number `1`, then we get a different count of results each time.

New function:

```
function getHardcodedTime(){
    return 1;
}
```

New query: `SELECT count(1) FROM c WHERE c._ts >= udf.getHardcodedTime()`

Results vary with 7240, 7236, 7233, 7264, etc. (This set is the actual order of responses from Cosmos DB.)

Comment: I don't see problems with the use of udf, and I cannot reproduce the problem with Cosmos DB Emulator. What would you get if you run `SELECT udf.getHardcodedTime() FROM c`?

Comment: I get many objects returned where the object contains the valuefrom the function. Here is a snippet.
    [
        {"$1": 1500000006 },
        ...
        { "$1": 1500000006} 
    ]

Comment: Could it be that you get continuation token in the select-using-udf case? If cosmosDB does not deduce your udf is deterministic then it can no longer use an index and hence it would do a full scan.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate to Cosmos DB that the function is deterministic? I found some examples on how to do that with SQL databases, but I didn't find anything for Cosmos DB.

Comment: I don't think you can. But you can work around this issue by using SP, taking parameter from UDF and passing it to query as value. cumbersome, but should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your description, the most likely cause is that **the UDF version is slow and returns a partial result with continuation token instead of final result**.

The concept of continuation is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#ExecutingSqlQueries) as:

> If a query's results cannot fit within a single page of results, then the REST API returns a continuation token through the x-ms-continuation-token response header. Clients can paginate results by including the header in subsequent results.

The observed count variation could be caused by the query stopping for next page at slightly different times. Check the `x-ms-continuation` header to know if that's the case.

### Why is UDF slow?

UDF returning a constant is not the same as constant for the query. Correct me if you know better, but from CosmosDB side, it does not know that the specific UDF is actually deterministic, but assumes it could evaluate to any value and hence has to be executed for each document to check for a match. It means it cannot use an index and has to do a slow full scan.

### What can you do?

#### Option 1: Follow continuations

If you don't care about the performance, you could keep using the UDF and just follow the continuation until all rows are processed.

Some DocumentDB clients can do this for you (ex: .net API), so this may be the fastest fix if you are in a hurry. But beware, this does not scale (keeps getting slower and cost more and more RU) and you should not consider this a long-term solution.

#### Option 2: Drop UDF, use parameters

You could pass the `hardcodedTime` instead as parameter. This way the query execution engine would know the value, could use a matching index and give you correct results without the hassle of continuations.

I don't know which API you use, but related reading just in case: [Parameterized SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#parameterized-sql-queries).

#### Option 3: Wrap in stored proc

If you really-really must control the `hardcodedTime` in UDF then you could implement a server-side procedure which would:

1. query the `hardcodedTime` from UDF
2. query the documents, passing the `hardcodedTime` as parameter
3. return results as SP output.

It would use the UDF AND index, but brings a hefty overhead in the amount of code required. Do your math if keeping UDF is worth the extra effort in dev and maintenance.

Related documentation about SPs: [Azure Cosmos DB server-side programming: Stored procedures, database triggers, and UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because I believe that you're probably correct that it's continuation tokens that caused this and you have good recommendations for other scenarios. The difference is that I was viewing the results in the Azure Portal's Cosmos DB Data Explorer.

The part that had confused me and caused to write this question was that the Data Explorer displayed "Results 1 - 1" with a count of zero where zero is the incorrect count. But we eventually discovered that you need to keep clicking the "Next" button and manually sum any results that you find on each result set.

Comment: I just found some notes in Microsoft's documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#SelectClause, which says that aggregated results may be returned over a query page when using the Azure portal's Data Explorer.

"When using the Azure portal's Data Explorer, note that aggregation queries may return the partially aggregated results over a query page. The SDKs produces a single cumulative value across all pages."